# how to get this gradient working in chrome?

Tags: css, gradient

Right I have no idea how to get this gradient to work in chrome:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(25, 130, 185) 0%, rgb(3, 100, 150) 50%, rgb(1, 77, 117) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

I understand for chrome i need to use some webkit specific rules?

Comment: It would make helping you easier if you provided an example on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `-webkit-` vendor prefix (*the `to bottom` should be `top` for all browsers*)

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(25, 130, 185) 0%, rgb(3, 100, 150) 50%, rgb(1, 77, 117) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

For chrome use

```
-webkit-linear-gradient
```

also, use top instead of to bottom

Comment: Just adding that to it does nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you still need webkit specific rules for Chrome.  Try this syntax:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000), to(#000));
```

That should work for you.

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/

Answer (score 0):

I think the webkit prefix version would just be -webkit-linear-gradient.   Could your problem be that your first arg is "to bottom" instead of just "bottom"?

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(25, 130, 185) 0%, rgb(3, 100, 150) 50%, rgb(1, 77, 117) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(25, 130, 185) 0%, rgb(3, 100, 150) 50%, rgb(1, 77, 117) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

See this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/KAD2E/

Answer (score 0):

All recent browsers beside Webkit-based ones have dropped the prefix and implements the latest syntax: Fx (both regular and ESR), IE 10, Opera 12.10.

For Chrome and Safari you still need the old syntax, prefixed.

The original syntax (-webkit-gradient(linear, …) ) is no more needed as browsers needing it are almost no more used.

A last point: the standard way of doing it must always be the last property declared. That way, for a browser implemented it, it always has precedence on the older behavior that may be buggy.

So the right way to write it is:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(25, 130, 185) 0%, rgb(3, 100, 150) 50%, rgb(1, 77, 117) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(25, 130, 185) 0%, rgb(3, 100, 150) 50%, rgb(1, 77, 117) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

Source: [linear-gradient on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient)